# Merge 2 video files with their audio in a single file side by side

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, muxer

I need to merge 2 video files along with their audio in a single file, side by side.

I am able to merge 2 video files in single file but it's using the audio from first video file only, whereas I need to merge the audio of the second file as well.

Here's how I'm trying to do it:

`ffmpeg.exe -i input1.webm -vf "[in] scale=iw/2:ih/2, pad=2*iw:ih [left]; movie=input2.webm, scale=iw/2:ih/2 [right]; [left][right] overlay=main_w/2:0 [out]" -b:v 768k ouput.webm`

I have tried various way with `amerge` but no success. As I am new to FFMpeg, I am not sure how can I achieve this.

### **EDIT**

Below is FFMpeg Command I have used for merging both files as suggested by @occvtech, but it's still not merging the second audio stream.

`ffmpeg.exe -i 3.mp4 -i 4.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v] scale=iw/2:ih/2,pad=2*iw:ih[left];[1:v]scale=iw/2:ih/2[right];[left][right‌​]overlay=main_w/2:0 [out]" -map [out] -map 0:a -map 1:a -b:v 768k o5.mp4`

Below is the console output:

```
ffmpeg version N-72276-gf99fed7 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --
enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-l
ibilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enab
le-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --en
able-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --ena
ble-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc
 --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enabl
e-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --ena
ble-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 23.101 / 54. 23.101
  libavcodec     56. 39.101 / 56. 39.101
  libavformat    56. 33.101 / 56. 33.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 16.101 /  5. 16.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '3.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.23.106
  Duration: 00:00:13.52, start: 0.023220, bitrate: 968 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yu
v420p, 640x480, 889 kb/s, 10 fps, 10 tbr, 10240 tbn, 20 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp,
 76 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '4.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.23.106
  Duration: 00:00:14.92, start: 0.023220, bitrate: 1049 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yu
v420p, 640x480, 971 kb/s, 10 fps, 10 tbr, 10240 tbn, 20 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp,
 75 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[libx264 @ 040d20e0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 040d20e0] profile High, level 2.1
[libx264 @ 040d20e0] 264 - core 146 r2538 121396c - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Cop
yleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deb
lock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 m
e_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chro
ma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 i
nterlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1
b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=10 scenec
ut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=768 ratetol=1.0 qc
omp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'o5.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.33.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 640x24
0, q=-1--1, 768 kb/s, 10 fps, 10240 tbn, 10 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.39.101 libx264
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (libvo_aacenc) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100
Hz, mono, s16, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc56.39.101 libvo_aacenc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> scale (graph 0)
  overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #1:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (libvo_aacenc))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   27 fps= 26 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s
frame=   46 fps= 28 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:04.90 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s
frame=   80 fps= 37 q=16.0 size=     303kB time=00:00:08.29 bitrate= 298.8kbits/
frame=  117 fps= 43 q=15.0 size=     717kB time=00:00:11.99 bitrate= 489.9kbits/
Past duration 0.767570 too large
frame=  137 fps= 39 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1488kB time=00:00:14.94 bitrate= 815.8kbits
/s dup=0 drop=12
video:1247kB audio:234kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxin
g overhead: 0.504372%
[libx264 @ 040d20e0] frame I:1     Avg QP:10.60  size: 30577
[libx264 @ 040d20e0] frame P:36    Avg QP:10.78  size: 20384
[libx264 @ 040d20e0] frame B:100   Avg QP:15.41  size:  5116
[libx264 @ 040d20e0] consecutive B-frames:  0.7%  0.0% 17.5% 81.8%
[libx264 @ 040d20e0] mb I  I16..4: 13.2% 49.8% 37.0%
[libx264 @ 040d20e0] mb P  I16..4:  0.8% 10.7%  1.9%  P16..4: 17.7% 30.4% 29.0%
 0.0%  0.0%    skip: 9.6%
[libx264 @ 040d20e0] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  1.1%  0.0%  B16..8: 27.0% 20.2% 10.1%
 direct:15.3%  skip:26.3%  L0:35.6% L1:31.1% BI:33.3%
[libx264 @ 040d20e0] final ratefactor: 13.38
[libx264 @ 040d20e0] 8x8 transform intra:77.9% inter:38.4%
[libx264 @ 040d20e0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 96.3% 97.8% 97.5% inter: 46.4% 68.
0% 41.1%
[libx264 @ 040d20e0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 44%  4%  7% 44%
[libx264 @ 040d20e0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 41% 10% 19%  3%  6%  5%  5%
 6%  5%
[libx264 @ 040d20e0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 25% 16%  9%  5% 12% 10%  9%
 7%  6%
[libx264 @ 040d20e0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 66% 12% 12% 10%
[libx264 @ 040d20e0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 040d20e0] ref P L0: 46.3% 12.0% 28.7% 13.0%
[libx264 @ 040d20e0] ref B L0: 81.1% 16.0%  2.9%
[libx264 @ 040d20e0] ref B L1: 93.2%  6.8%
[libx264 @ 040d20e0] kb/s:745.10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the [`amerge` audio filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge) to combine both audio streams into one:

```
ffmpeg -i input0.mp4 -i input1.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]scale=iw/2:-1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[left]; \
 [1:v]scale=iw/2:-1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[right]; \
 [left][right​]hstack[v]; \
 [0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" output
```

- This will make a stereo output with the audio from `input0.mp4` in the left channel, and the audio from `input1.mp4` in the right channel. You did not specify how you want the resulting channels arranged, but if you prefer a mono output then add `-ac 1` before the output file name.
- [`hstack`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hstack) can replace `pad` + `overlay`. `hstack` is simpler and likely faster.

Answer (score 2):

Before I begin - know that there are many ways to do the same thing within FFmpeg.

That said, in your case, I would personally prefer using the `-filter_complex` argument instead of `-vf`, and I would specify all of my input files with the `-i` flag.  I find it easier to map them later on.

To answer you question, try the following command:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input1.webm -i input2.webm -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=iw/2:ih/2,pad=2*iw:ih[left];[1:v]scale=iw/2:ih/2[right];[left][right]overlay=main_2/2:0[out]" -map [out] -map 0:a -map 1:a -b:v 768k output.webm
```

I personally would also specifically reference my desired audio and video codecs here with the `-c:v` and `-c:a` flags.  I don't like letting FFmpeg decide for me.

Note:  I haven't tested the above command.  I am used to using `overlay=shortest=1:x=...:y=...` for overlaying.  But again, more than one way to do most things in FFmpeg

Comment: I have tried your given command, but then also its not merging audio of second video. below is command I have use for your reference. 

`ffmpeg.exe -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=iw/2:ih/2,pad=2*iw:ih[left];[1:v]scale=iw/2:ih/2[right];[left][right]overlay=main_w/2:0[out]" -map [out] -map 0:a -map 1:a -b:v 768k output.mp4`

Can you help me on this?

Comment: Can you please edit your original post to include the console output?

Comment: FFmpeg doesn't appear to be mapping your audio for stream 0:1.  I highly recommend choosing what audio codec (and video codec for that matter) to use instead of letting FFmpeg decide for you.   Try using an uncompressed audio codec for now for testing - if the file size is too big for you, you can always compress the audio to another format.  Try adding `-c:a pcm_s16le` after your `-map 1:a` in the command you used above.